# How do I write the action to loop through layouts?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, xmonad

Currently, I have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to loop though the layouts, which is the default.

I would like to bind that action to another key combination, e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, in order to let the original one free for a launcher application (which is a lot in my muscle memory as I use i3, whereas my muscle memory has nothing to loop though layouts, so I can absorb any new one for it).

My understanding is that I should so something like this

```hs
def { {- my defaults -} }
    `removeKeysP` ["M-<Space>"]
    `additionalKeysP` myKeys

myKeys = ("M-S-<Space>", ???) : [{- other stuff -}]
```

but I don't know how to write the action `???`; the only think I (think I) know is that its type should be `X ()`. Well, thanks :D

Besides giving me a solution, would you mind helping me undestand how I should have found it myself? I do use HLS in my IDE, but I'm not sure how to use it I don't even know in which module I'd find what I look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial config is defined in [https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Config.hs](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/c4cf4715f736fed77fb2af622c0760259ac2cf43/src/XMonad/Config.hs#L193). On line 193, you can find the message triggered by <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

```hs
sendMessage NextLayout
```

You may also be interested in looking through more elaborate Actions from contrib in https://xmonad.github.io/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/, like [CycleSelectedLayouts](https://xmonad.github.io/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-CycleSelectedLayouts.html) for example.

Comment: Is [line 260 in `Config.hs`](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/c4cf4715f736fed77fb2af622c0760259ac2cf43/src/XMonad/Config.hs#L260) the definition of the `def` I'm editing in the `xmonad.hs` file? Do I find `Config.hs` somewhere on my system? Or is it compiled into some binary? Thanks for the other links!

Comment: @Enlico Yes, this is the original `def` you derive from. As far as I can tell, by issuing `xmonad --recompile` the core itself is not recompiled, so there's no need to keep `Config.hs` around. But its mere presence on your disk may actually depend on the way you installed XMonad (via Cabal, your distro's package manager, etc.). Here's a [guided tour of the XMonad source](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Guided_tour_of_the_xmonad_source) I found enlightening regarding all the data types and how they are tossed around (esp. `Core.hs` and `StackSet.hs`).